# What is the best way to restore a Hyper-V VM server?

Tags: windows-server-2012, backup-restoration, hyper-v-server-2012

I backed up a hyper-V VM 2012 server on to a network share to try to run through the process of restoring.  I used the windows iso on the VM  and selected to restore from the network back up. Everything  was restoring fine, but towards the end of the process I received the following error: the post recovery operation to set registry keys for automated system recovery in the offline operation system failed. (This was a healthy VM with no issues)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If its the VM guest your trying to restore, simply export the VM to the network share. this can be scripted in powershell. If you want to restore it just go to hyper-v manager and select import vm. 
 https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848491.aspx

```
Export-VM –Name Test –Path D:\
```

Comment: Thanks,  I will try this. So basically I should export/import as opposed to back-up/restore correct?  Even though I got the error message I was able to boot up the VM server and it appears to be working OK however  I'm really worried about the error message.

Comment: Yeah, i help run a vm infrastructure and thats what we do whenever we want to do something like that. You can also copy the raw vhdx file as well, thats the hard disk.

Comment: Also I might add to be careful in a production environment, the machine will have same name/ip/mac/etc, if both are up at the same time. It could cause conflicts and issues.